# Do I need to get re-immunized for immunities received prior to contracting measles?

Tags: immune-system, vaccination, chickenpox, measles

[One study](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4823017/) has suggested that measles can lead to "immune memory loss", meaning immunities gained prior to measles infection can be lost.

I had measles at age six. According to the (current) CDC [schedule for immunizations](https://www.cdc.gov/vaccines/schedules/hcp/imz/child-adolescent.html), much of my presumed immune response was developed from vaccinations prior to age 6 and thus seems to me to possibly be at risk. Also, I had chickenpox and other infections prior to having the measles.

Is it recommended to get re-immunized for things I was exposed to (via vaccine or infection) prior to having the measles?